# Function Help: Extract specific content from email body with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help customizing paramiters of the `extractValueFromBody` function in the script that I am using to extract content from an HTML email. The script that I am using works well except I can not get content to populate for (2) types of fields that are differnt than all the others in the HTML email - URLs from a button text and fields which its content is not place right after the colon (:).

The code that I am using looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var email = messages[j];
      var body = email.getPlainBody();
      var subject = email.getSubject();
      var from = email.getFrom();
      var to = email.getTo();
      var cc = email.getCc();
      var time = email.getDate();

      // Extracting fields from the email body
      var offMarketOrOn = extractValueFromBody(body, "Off Market or On Market:");
      var retailPrice = extractValueFromBody(body, "Retail Price:");
      var listPrice = extractValueFromBody(body,"List Price:");
      var customJob = extractValueFromBody(body,"Custom Job:");
      var doorSeats = extractValueFromBody(body,"Doors/Seats:");
      var autoAddress = extractValueFromBody(body,"Auto Address:");
      var hPower = extractValueFromBody(body,"Horse Power:");
      var builtIn = extractValueFromBody(body,"Built in:");
      var leaseAmount = extractValueFromBody(body,"What it will lease for:");
      var linkToMap = extractValueFromBody(body, "Link to Map:");
      var linkToOnlineListing = extractValueFromBody(body,"Link to Online Listing:");
      var suggestedAmount = extractValueFromBody(body,"Suggested Amount:");
      var personalNotes = extractValueFromBody(body,"Personal Notes:");

      data.push([subject, time, offMarketOrOn, retailPrice, listPrice, customJob, doorSeats, autoAddress, hPower, builtIn, leaseAmount, linkToMap, linkToOnlineListing, suggestedAmount, personalNotes]);
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

// Helper funtion to extract values from email body based on a field
function extractValueFromBody(body, field) {
  var startIndex = body.indexOf(field);
  if (startIndex !== -1) {
    startIndex += field.length + 1; // Adding 1 to skip the colon (:)
    var endIndex = body.indexOf("\n", startIndex);
    return body.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
  }
```

This works - meaning I see the output from the HTML email in my Google Sheet - for all email var fields except for `autoAddress`, `linkToMap`, and `linkToOnlineListing`.

Both the `linkToMap`, and `linkToOnlineListing` are HREF text buttons with URLs. I would like to extact the URL and populate my Google Sheet with the URL.

The `autoAddress` text within the HTML is followed by an address by the address does not display on the same line as the "Auto Address:" body text. The address appears 2 lines below the "Auto Address:" body text but is the very next peace of text within the email. With the code that I have, I am unable to extract the address. (my guess is because the actual address is not on the same line or that close to the "Auto Address:" body text)

I'm not a programer - just learning on my own - but would really like some help or pointers making these last few modifications. Thank you!